# Matching VBN Textbox Text with Autonumber With Custom Format in Access

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have an access database where "Orders" is my table with the column name CusID and is set to Autonumber with format "CUS"0001

I'm trying to read an autonumber with the custom format "CUS0001" from VBN but I can't seem to read it.

I've tried to read it all as a string, but I can't seem to read it.

```
cmdCustomer.CommandText = "Select * From Orders Where CusID = " & (txtCusID.Text) & ";"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, AutoNumber values are numbers.  "CUS0001" is clearly not a number so clearly cannot be stored in that column.  When you specify a format in Access, that relates ONLY to how the Access application displays that data.  It says nothing about how the data is stored.  If Access displays a value in that column as "CUS0001" then the column actually contains the number 1 and that is all that your VB app will see, so that's how you have to query it.  Also, if you want the value displayed as "CUS0001" in your app then YOU are going to have to format it that way.

It's also worth noting that, if you really did want to search for "CUS0001" then you'd have to wrap that value in single quotes in your SQL code or else you're going to get a syntax error.  That said, it shouldn't matter because you should be using a parameter to insert that value into your SQL code.

Comment: So for example, if access displays "CUS0001" then I would have to enter "1". But what if I want it to accept the entire "CUS0001" to be read. What would I have to do for that to work?

This is what I have in mind. 
Get the first 3 letters in "CUS0001" as a string then "0001" as a number so both can be validated. Will it work?

Comment: As I said, the column contains numbers and so, if you want to filter on that column, you have to specify a number.  If the user enters a string that contains digits prefixed with "CUS" then you need to strip the prefix and then convert the remaining text to an `Integer`.